# Referencing the primary key twice as foreign key in MS Access using SQL is causing an error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get an error when I try to reference the primary key as a foreign key in other queries:

> There is already a relationship named " DepartmentNameFK" in the current database.

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT 
(
    ProjectID varchar(50),
    Name varchar(50),
    MaxHours FLOAT,
    StartDate Date,
    EndDate Date,
    DepartmentName varchar(50),

    CONSTRAINT ProjectIDPK PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID),
    CONSTRAINT DepartmentNameFK FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName) **[ so here I am referencing for the second time, THIS IS NOT PART OF CODE, JUST EXPLANATION]**
REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems very clear - you **already have** a foreign key constraint by the name of `DepartmentNameFK` - but all database objects (and constraints are database objects) must have a **unique, separate** name so you can refer to them.

So here - just call your FK constraint **something else**:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT 
(
    ProjectID varchar(50),
    Name varchar(50),
    MaxHours FLOAT,
    StartDate Date,
    EndDate Date,
    DepartmentName varchar(50),

    CONSTRAINT ProjectIDPK PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID),
    -- just call the constraint **SOMETHING ELSE** other than "DepartmentNameFK"
    CONSTRAINT DepartmentNameFK2 
        FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName)
        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

My suggestion would be to name your FK constraints

```
FK_(parent table)_(referenced table)
```

so in your case:

```
FK_Project_Department
```

If your other FK is in another table, it would be

```
FK_OtherTable_Department
```

and thus you would *not* have any clashes of already existing names.....

Comment: Damnn, thank you so much, didn't know that I can name different. I appreciate it.